# how to Send mail with attachment from your outlook account using Python

Tags: python

i have tried below code to send attachment, but file is not sending , only content is sending. please help.

```
SERVER = "smtp.example.com"
FROM = "yourEmail@example.com"
TO = ["listOfEmails"] # must be a list

    enter code here

SUBJECT = "Subject"
TEXT = "Your Text"

# Prepare actual message
message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

DNSFile="abc.csv"
# Send the mail
import smtplib
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(DNSFile)

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code I use is to send attachments using Python is:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders

## FILE TO SEND AND ITS PATH
filename = 'some_file.csv'
SourcePathName  = 'C:/reports/' + filename 

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'from@domain.com'
msg['To'] = 'to@domain.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Report Update'
body = 'Body of the message goes in here'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

## ATTACHMENT PART OF THE CODE IS HERE
attachment = open(SourcePathName, 'rb')
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)  ### put your relevant SMTP here
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('from@domain.com', 'password_here')  ### if applicable
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Hope this works for you. This works for me like a charm.

Comment: I changed SMTP server to imap-mail.outlook.com, also created an "app password" because I had two step verification enabled. Then this script works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else finds themselves here in 2022;
Here are the Updated IMAP, POP, and SMTP Settings for Outlook.com:

- **IMAP Server Name:** outlook.office365.com
- **IMAP Port:** 993
- **IMAP Encryption Method:** TLS
- **POP Server Name:** outlook.office365.com
- **POP Port:** 995
- **POP Encryption Method:** TLS
- **SMTP Server Name:** smtp-mail.outlook.com
- **SMTP Port:** 587
- **SMTP Encryption Method:** STARTTLS

[***Source***](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040)